# Determine saving moves for a checked king

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

In my chess code I explore the whole tree of possible movements to find saving moves for a checked king. That is, for every one of the checked king's side pieces I search their whole tree of moves and keep those that remove the king from check in a list.

Not like it's particularly expensive computationally-wise with a board of 8x8, but just for the sake of knowledge - is there a more efficient algorithm to calculate the saving moves?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try to directly use the geometry the attacking piece and possible defenders to see if an intersection is available. This would be faster.
But there is a lot of cases to be taken into consideration : multiple checks, pinned defenders, half-pinned defenders, *en passant* rules... It's much easier to code that wrong, so be careful, and prepare lots of test cases to compare to the "simple" version, to check that you're not mixing things up.

Computing "long" lists of legal moves isn't hard for a computer, there's less than 200 anyway. What's hard in chess computer programs is the exponential search tree  and deciding when to stop recursing and evaluate.